# Combining Time-Defined Hazard Ratios and Odds Ratios in Meta-Analysis

Tags: meta-analysis, odds-ratio, hazard

I am attempting to complete a meta-analysis of studies that variously report Odds Ratio of death at 30 days, and Hazard Ratios for death at 30 days.

All are reported as being close to 1 (range 1.2-1.99).

Similar questions here suggest that the time-component of HR makes comparisons to OR useless, but I was wondering if the time-constrained HRs reported in these studies may make these more appropriate for direct comparison, or if there was a transformation that I could apply to make these directly comparable?

Many thanks